# rails console unable to connect to database in staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, console

Using capistrano I'm deploying my Rails 4 app under the environment name "staging". When I ssh onto the server and run `rails console`, any ActiveRecord queries I do come up with `no such table`. So I check my `Rails.env` and sure enough it reads `development` instead of `staging`. But even running `rails console staging`, it does set `Rails.env` to "staging", but still the ActiveRecord queries say no such table. The app itself is running fine (under Apache and Passenger), but for some reason the rails console is unable to connect to the db.

I've reverted back to when I knew it was working and am still seeing the error, which tells me it is a configuration change i must've made on the server as opposed to a change to the rails app code or capistrano deploy config.

Answer (score 1):

OK, tracked down the answer myself. The RAILS_ENV was originally being set to staging in `/etc/environment` -- but a while ago this file was removed during some debugging, and not restored.

What does still surprise me is that

```
rails console staging
```

does not have the same effect as

```
export RAILS_ENV=staging
rails console
```

anyhow, sorted.